# How create endpoints in multiple files?

Tags: python, flask

I'm building an API in using Flkas, but when I try place endpoints at multiple files importing with "import" to organize my api, only works one file route.

My first file **teste.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)
import teste2

livros = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'título': 'O Senhor dos Anéis - A Sociedade do Anel',
        'autor': 'J.R.R Tolkien'
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'título': 'Harry Potter e a Pedra Filosofal',
        'autor': 'J.K Howling'
    },
    {
        'id': 3,
        'título': 'James Clear',
        'autor': 'Hábitos Atômicos'
    },
]

# Consultar(todos)
@app.route('/livros',methods=['GET'])
def obter_livros():
    return jsonify(livros)

# Consultar(id)
@app.route('/livros/<int:id>',methods=['GET'])
def obter_livro_por_id(id):
    for livro in livros:
        if livro.get('id') == id:
            return jsonify(livro)
# Editar
@app.route('/livros/<int:id>',methods=['PUT'])
def editar_livro_por_id(id):
    livro_alterado = request.get_json()
    for indice,livro in enumerate(livros):
        if livro.get('id') == id:
            livros[indice].update(livro_alterado)
            return jsonify(livros[indice])
# Criar
@app.route('/livros',methods=['POST'])
def incluir_novo_livro():
    novo_livro = request.get_json()
    livros.append(novo_livro)

    return jsonify(livros)
# Excluir
@app.route('/livros/<int:id>',methods=['DELETE'])
def excluir_livro(id):
    for indice, livro in enumerate(livros):
        if livro.get('id') == id:
            del livros[indice]

    return jsonify(livros)

app.run(port=5000,host='localhost',debug=True)
```

My second file **teste2.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)

livros2 = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'título': 'only a teste',
        'autor': 'J.R.R Tolkien'
    },
]

# Consultar(todos)
@app.route('/livross',methods=['GET'])
def obter_livros():
    return jsonify(livros2)

app.run(port=5000,host='localhost',debug=True)
```

When I run `teste.py`, only **teste2.py**'s endpoints works... How can I make all endpoints work without putting everything in one file?

Comment: if you want to put routes in different files, you should use blueprints.

Comment: Well, you can't do `app.run` in teste2.py.  That will never return, so the rest of your first app (after the import) never runs.  The problem here is that each file has its own copy of `app`, and I don't know how Flask handles that.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf i googled it and find my solution with blueprints, ty so much <3

Answer (score 1):

In order to have view functions in different files, Flask's documentation recommends using [blueprints](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/blueprints/).

In your case, you can try something like:

**`teste.py`**

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, Blueprint

first_blueprint = Blueprint('first_blueprint', __name__)


# notice the change in the route
@first_blueprint.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def obter_livros():
   ...

# notice change in the path
@first_blueprint.route('/<int:id>',methods=['GET'])
def obter_livro_por_id(id):
    ...


# do the same for the other view functions in the file
# in the other file also create a blueprint
```

In the file where you are creating your Flask app:

```
from flask import App
from teste import first_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(first_blueprint, url_prefix='/livros')
# register the other blueprint
```